# Change enumerate algorithm to show greater ranges first

Tags: c, algorithm, logic

I have a program that needs the enumerate algorithm, I got it to work this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void show (int subs[], int k) {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=k; i++)
        printf("%i ", subs[i]);
    puts("");
}

void enumerate (int n) {
    int subs[n+1], k = 0;
    *subs = 0;
    while (1) {
       if (subs[k] < n) {
            subs[k+1] = subs[k] + 1;
            k++;
        } else {
            subs[k-1] += 1;
            k--;
        }
        if (k == 0) break;
        show (subs, k);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    enumerate(4);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[ideone](http://ideone.com/7pWvyK)</kbd>

As it should be, it does O(2<sup>N</sup>) calls to `show(subs, k)`. Initially, I thought it would give no problem, but I was wrong. Actually my program takes:

```
2 secs for n=25
4 secs for n=26
9 secs for n=27
18 secs for n=28
...
```

As you can see, its time grows very quickly. My program also does a quicksort, and instead of `show`, it calls another function with my logic, but it doesn't matter here.

But as I have to do it faster, I started analyzing my problem...

I stated that if my desired solution is found in the sequence `1 2 4 5` (range length of 4) for example, all sequences with range length lower than that is worthless for my logic.

Then, I tried to code the `enumerate` function shown above in such a way the sequences with greater ranges shows up first, because if I get this, I can simply break the enumerate function when I find the desired value.

But after about two hours struggling I found myself with 4 inner loops (!!) and with wrong sequences.

Can you ninjas help me with that please? Thanks in advance.

#### Update

If you run `enumerate(3)` you will get:

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 3 
2 
2 3 
3
```

What I want, is greater range lengths first, so:

```
1 2 3 
1 2 
1 3 
2 3 
1 
2 
3
```

Comment: I see some random code with no clear purpose.  What is the actual goal of your program?

Comment: @btilly. I tried to show only the relevant part of the code.. Or did you mean an clear example? I will update with one

Comment: So you only want the last block? (i.e.) You have `1 2 3` but do _not_ need other 3-sequences such as `3 2 1` or `2 3 1` or `1 3 2`? And, you don't need a `2 1`? If so, there is a slight extension to your algorithm above that can give them in order [greater range first] without the need of a sort. I've had to do this sort of thing before, but I had different output requirements, so I'm just trying to understand yours before offering an answer.

Comment: @CraigEstey. My program reads `x` intervals (start and end times as integers), and returns the maximun _disjoint intervals_. the _x_ value is given. Sorry my English terms, I don't know if they are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the size of your output grows like `2n`, not `n2`.  Hence your performance problem.  Reordering may help, but rethinking your algorithm is likely to help more.

But that said, here is a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void show (int subs[], int k) {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=k; i++)
        printf("%i ", subs[i]);
    puts("");
}

void enumerate (int n) {
    int subs[n+1], k = n, l = 0;
    *subs = 0;
    // Populate subs with longest possible sequence.
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
       subs[i] = i;
    }
    while (0 < k) {
       show(subs, k);
       // Find first increasible spot 
       l = 0;
       for (int i = k; 0 < i; i--) {
          if (subs[i] + k - i < n) {
             l = i;
             break;
          }
       }
       if (0 < l) {
          // Create our increasing sequence
          subs[l]++;
          for (int i = l+1; i <= n; i++) {
             subs[i] = subs[i-1] + 1;
          }
       }
       else {
          // Make k shorter and reset the sequence.
          k = k-1;
          for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
             subs[i] = i;
          }
       }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    enumerate(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome +1!! I was trying to do this five hours till now.. I will try it right now and see the results. Also, I don't know why I wrote n^2, I meant 2^n.. thanks for that too